# Actionscript: how to pass objects to a loader event

Tags: flash, actionscript

What is the recommended way of passing objects into the eventhandlers of a Loader?

```
        var l:Loader = new Loader();
        var o:Object = new Object();
        l.tag = o; // i imagine something like this
        l.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, splashCompleted);
        l.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, splashIoerror);         
        l.load(new URLRequest(path));


        function splashCompleted(e:Event):void
        {
            // here i want to access the object o
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why would you need to do that? If there are many loaders and you want to associate some data with each of them, it would be better to write either subclass or wrapper class to store your data. For example, let's consider subclass:

```
public class TaggedLoader extends Loader
{
    public var tag:Object;
}
```

Using `TaggedLoader` instead of `Loader` you can easily access data associated with the loader object:

```
var l:Loader = new TaggedLoader();
var o:Object = new Object();

l.tag = o;
l.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener( Event.COMPLETE, splashCompleted );
l.load( new URLRequest( path ) );

function splashCompleted( e:Event ):void
{
    var taggedLoader:TaggedLoader = ( e.currentTarget as LoaderInfo ).loader as TaggedLoader;
    var tag:Object = taggedLoader.tag;
}
```

Also it is possible to use maps (`Object` or `Dictionary`), but maps are worse in terms of performance.

Comment: thanks, i was just thinking that AS has a built in way for that like other languages like C# already have.

Answer (score 0):

You can access the `Loader` from inside the event handler using this:

```
( e.currentTarget as LoaderInfo ).loader
```